# Quartz C# Scheduler - Prevent Job from automatically retrying after 15 minutes

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I want to run a job that will take a long time to complete. However after 15 minutes, the trigger is being re-fired before the job has completed. I guess this is a default fail safe to handle jobs that have failed. How can I increase this timeout to something like 30 minutes?

Here is my job scheduler code:

```
var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity(triggerName, triggerGroup)
            .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder
                .CronSchedule(cronExpression).InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Utc))
                .Build();

var scheduleRequestJob = JobBuilder.Create<T>()
            .WithIdentity(taskName, taskGroup)
            .Build();

        _scheduler.ScheduleJob(scheduleRequestJob, trigger);
```

Comment: There is no such fail safe time in Quartz. How is the CronTrigger defined (cronExpression)?

Comment: @Rabban The cron expression for this particular job is "0 30 12 ? * MON-FRI *". Every weekday at 12:30pm

Comment: Historically this is handled by the task creating a pid/lock file and while the lock file is there refusing to start a second copy

Comment: The expression looks good to me. I write you an answer how to prevent this strange behaviour with some extra explanations. Just give me some minutes ;)

Answer (score 1):

Quartz has no Fail safe time. There are just 2 possibilities that Quartz would retrigger your job.

1. The trigger execution time is to short and it will trigger before the last run has ended. As we can see from your CronExpression that this is not the case.
2. Your job throws an [`JobExecutionException`](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html) - [(Api)](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/html/e155e960-3c46-0d5e-03fa-943f60544743.htm), this will reschedule your Job immediately.

To prevent that a Job is run more than once at the same time, add the [`DisallowConcurrentExecutionAttribute`](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html) - [(Api)](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/html/89688e7d-3f32-fb19-c3b1-0e05e479a10d.htm) to your class.

```
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class MyJob: IJob
{
}
```

this ensures the behaviour you want.

Comment: I'm not sure an exception is being thrown. It retried 5 times, exactly 15 minutes after the previous trigger. Luckily after the 5th time the job completed in 14 minutes and 16 seconds so didn't retry. Is it possible something is causing JobExecutionException to be thrown after 15 minutes? This same job has been running for the last few months without any problems. Will DisallowConcurrentExecution prevent the same job running more than once?

Comment: @Dan_Dan_Man Yes it will prevent this. I will edit my answer to make it more clear. The `JobExecutionException` has to be thrown explicitly by you to work as describe. Currently i can't explain why Quartz tries to retrigger your already running job. Please ensure that your Job runs without exception and don't throws the `JobExecutionException`.

Comment: Okay thank you. I will try this and let you know how it goes. It is possible for exceptions to be thrown in my jobs but I don't ever throw a JobExecutionException. Although in this particular situation I don't think any exceptions were thrown.